# Actionscript Mobile Project - x=0; y=0l is Not in the Upper Left Corner. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, swc

I am a pretty experienced Flash developer. I usually compile from the IDE, but this time i decided to build from Flash Builder and bring in all the assets as swc(s).

Here is the code:

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;


    public class RuFood_v2 extends Sprite
    {
        private var _stage:Object;


        public function RuFood_v2()
        {
            super();
            trace("what's good bro?");

            var _searchBox:SearchBox = new SearchBox();
            var _homeScreen:HomeScreen = new HomeScreen();
            var _rect:Rect = new Rect();


            _stage = stage;

            _stage.addChild(_rect);
            _stage.addChild(_homeScreen);
            _stage.addChild(_searchBox);

            _homeScreen.x = 0;
            _homeScreen.y = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

the things "SearchBox, HomeScreen, and Rect are all library symbols brought in through the swc. They look like this in the IDE:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But then this is what it looks like when I debug!

[image]

What's with all the white space at the top? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: When you say "the IDE" are you referring to Flash Professional, right?  Flash Builder is also an IDE.

Comment: Yes. Flash Professional. I am just wondering why the coordinates are so -200 for y is at the top. Is it like that for everyone??

Answer (score 0):

try

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```